# how to set an int to be inbetween numbers

Tags: java, android

So lets say you want to make a grading program. Well you would want to set a int named 'aGrade' then you would set that to equal 100 to 90. Well if you had the grade 95. so int grade = 95; then you wanted to check all this how would you check if 95 is inbetween 100 and 90?

Comment: Let's say I want, but why would I?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: you would say `grade >= 90 && grade <= 100`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this you can check for any number in a range.

```
   if(grade >=90){
        //do something
    }
   else if(grade >=80 && grade <=89){
        //do something
    }
  else if(grade >=70 && grade <=79){
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: Pretty sure you only need to check the lower bound. If it's not `>= 90` then it must be one of the others. IOW, if it passes one if the upper bound is set by that if failing. Except, I guess, for 100 if that's reasonable or required.